# finding distribution $\mathbb{Z}$ in problem

Tags: probability

suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is random sample of $Exp(0,\sigma)$. if $\mathbb{S_n}=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n$
and $\mathbb{Z}=\max\{n:\mathbb{S_n}\leq s\}$ how can find distribution $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(S_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is the set of events of a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) $(N_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ with intensity $\sigma$ and that $Z=N_s$ counts the number of events before time $s$. Hence, the distribution of $Z$ is Poisson with parameter $s\cdot\sigma$.